# Will be there no ISS in 2030s according to current plans in 2019?

Tags: iss, future-missions

While it took about [10 years and 30 missions](https://www.issnationallab.org/about/iss-timeline/) to assemble the ISS, and its end of life is about [mid to end of 2020'](http://www.spacedaily.com/reports/ISS_end_of_life_options_999.html)s, is there any plan to plan for a new ISS?

Otherwise, the time window might become too short for delivering a new ISS<sup>1</sup>? Or is there just no need anymore for such a thing if other projects will work well like Moon gateway, Moon base, Mars missions?

<sup>1</sup> possibly, some years from now, building an ISS might take less time and less missions due to new technologies like 3D printing and advanced transportation, nevertheless there is a planning effort and possibly also the specifications might become more demanding.

Comment: ISS is currently an enormous money hog; cost of maintaining it is one of primary roadblocks in exploration of the Moon and Mars. Many people want it gone with no replacement, for no other reason than freeing up the budget for other missions. Simultaneously, Russians aren't interested in ditching it and consider detaching the Russian segment and running it as a standalone station in case ISS is to be deorbited.

Comment: This seems highly speculative (and thus off-topic), but there is usually a lot of commotion as the lease on life comes to an end, resulting in an extension. Extending it wins political points in the US on the basis of being 1st/the best, while investing in the future, in science, and in national defense, so it's likely to continue. I have read somewhere already that some plans have been made or put before Congress to extend the mission life to the mid 30s. However, the US & Russia have also been "officially" working on a replacement since 2015.

Comment: @TylerH the question indeed means to say that as the ISS will come to end you can't just take one out of the pocket. There is also some physical life limit or.

Comment: The Russian stance is a serious political/PR problem. The Russian segments are the oldest of all, and if they remain space-worthy, it would suggest either the Western segments were deorbited prematurely (not used to their full extent, some of expense of building them and putting them in space wasted) or they were built inferior to Russian, less durable, worse. It's still just the same silly posturing and flexing as in the Cold War (the Shuttle being such a money sink, kept for political reasons) but it seems ISS may remain in orbit until Russians decide it's EOL time for their segments too.

Comment: ...so, in short, current plans are, yes, there will be no ISS in 2030s. But as history and current political climate suggest, the current plans are unlikely to survive.

Comment: Let's add Dragon 2 is almost ready to fly, and some serious funds were put in it. Removing its only destination and purpose of existence would make funding it very questionable.

Comment: Why is it always assumed that ceasing to operate the ISS means deorbiting it? Seems like a waste.

Comment: @ikrase If you cease to operate the ISS it will deorbit naturally. Part of its operations include manually boosting its orbit back up periodically.

Comment: It might be possible to raise ISS to a much higher orbit. Didn't work out very well for Skylab, but one can always try raising it to an even higher orbit. One significant problem with that is it would most definitely become uninhabitable, being placed in Van Allen belts.

Comment: Some parts of the ISS are 20 years old and critical to the stations functioning. It's old. Technology has gotten a lot better since the first components were launched. Also, Starship will be able to provide the entire pressurized volume of the ISS in a single launch. Even if starship is delayed by 5 years, that's still before 2030.

Comment: @Dragongeek Is that even remotely true?

Comment: @Swike The first module of the ISS was launched in 1998. The pressurized volume of the ISS is ~1000 cubic meters and the starship's pressurized volume is about the same (~1000 m^3). The big difference is that the ISS has a mass of 420 tons and the starship's cargo to LEO is only 150 tons. If the starship docks with the ISS, the volume of liveable space is doubled and a duplicate ISS could be built (by mass) with only ~3 starship launches.

Comment: @Dragongeek wow, that's really spectacular

Comment: ...assuming the Starship schedule is remotely realistic. SpaceX delivers all kinds of wonders on awesome budget but their schedule announcements are regularly optimistic beyond all reason and tend to slip by order of +100% or more. I'm not holding my breath for Starship before 2030.